# VueJS this in lodash throttled method

Tags: vue.js, lodash

I am trying to throttle a method in my VueJS application. I tried the following at first:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething () {
            console.log('olas')
        }
    },
    created () {
        _.throttle(this.doSomething,200)
    }
}
```

But the `doSomething` method was just not fired: https://jsfiddle.net/z4peade0/

Then, I tried this:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething: _.throttle( () => {
            console.log('olas')
        },200)
    },
    created () {
        this.doSomething()
    }
}
```

And the functiong gets triggered: https://jsfiddle.net/z4peade0/1/

Problem is, I can't access the `foo` property inside the throttled method:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething: _.throttle( () => {
            console.log(this.foo) // undefined
        },200)
    },
    created () {
        this.doSomething()
    }
}
```

I tried to do something like:

```
const self = {
    ...
    methods: {
        doSomething: _.throttle( () => {
            console.log(self.foo) 
        },200)
    },
    ...
}

export default self
```

without success

**How could I use lodash throttled method on a VueJS method, and using `this` context?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're using an arrow function, which binds the wrong context (`this`). You should use a plain `function`:

```
    doSomething: _.throttle( function () {
        console.log('olas', this.foo);
    },200)
```

Comment: Works great, I didn't know that at all, thank you very much

Comment: (For further reading) The different behavior of the arrow function compared to the default is also documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions